# Create sequence in h2 database

Tags: sql, hibernate, h2

I want to create a sequence in h2 database for the below entity

```
public class Label {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "label_sequence")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "label_sequence", sequenceName = "label_sequence", allocationSize = 100)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private String value;
}
```

Below is the sql command I am executing

```
CREATE SEQUENCE label_sequence
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  MINVALUE 1;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE SEQUENCE LABEL_SEQUENCE
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  MINVALUE[*] 1 "; SQL statement:
CREATE SEQUENCE label_sequence
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  MINVALUE 1 [42000-140]
```

The below query works

```
CREATE SEQUENCE label_sequence
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1;
```

But I am getting ID values less than 1 because of the allocation size I guess.

How can I make sure the ID values never go below 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a very old version of H2 database, H2 1.2.140 was released 10 years ago. You need to use some modern version that knows this syntax.

If you really need to use such archaic version, just remove `MINVALUE` clause, your sequence will generate values 1, 2, … 9223372036854775807, so you have enough time before the overflow. You can add a `CHECK` constraint to your column for more safety, if you wish.

Comment: When using the latest version, the minvalue problem is solved. But I am still getting negative ID values.

Comment: It means that your applications passes negative values to H2 and sequence isn't actually used.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "MY_OWN_SEQ" 
MINVALUE 1 
MAXVALUE 999999999 
INCREMENT BY 1 
START WITH 202700 
NOCACHE 
NOCYCLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must also add Mode=Oracle to the properties file to be Oracle compatible with sequence request syntax.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64799048

Comment: The question is about sequence creation, not about Oracle compatibility mode.